# C++ filling array of structure from file

Tags: c++, file, structure

Hi I need to read a file and get data from file to array of structure.

Structure

```
struct Activity {
    string ID;
    string Name;
    string quantity; };
```

I have this function for reading from file

```
int* fillStructure(ifstream &fileActivity){


    int i=0;
    int numberOfElements = numberOfLines(fileActivity);

    Activity* myActivity = new Activity[numberOfElements];

    while (i < numberOfElements)
    {
          getline(fileActivity, myAktivity[i].ID, ',');
          getline(fileActivity, myActivity[i].Name, ',');
          getline(fileActivity, myActivity[i].quantity, '\n');      
          i++;
    }

   fileActivity.close(); 
   return myActivity; }
```

And when i try in main function to print members of structures It doesnt work

```
int main(){



    if (!(fileActivity.is_open())){
        cout << "Error when reading file" << endl;
        return 0;
    }  

    fillStructure(fileActivity);

    cout << myActivity[1].ID << endl; return 0;  }
```

I am beginner, can you guys help me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. First thing you are doing wrong is using C language tag on a C++ question. Your code is no valid C code. Then you should read a few pages first: [the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This will show you that a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ist a good thing to start with.

Comment: `myActivity` is a local variable. It does not exist outside of the `fillStructure` function.

Comment: Your fillStructure reads data from file? What does your getline function do? That's the interesting part

Comment: I edit the post now I am trying to return the array but it's still doesnt work. I am trying to read data from csv file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared `myActivity` in `void fillStructure(ifstream &fileActivity)`, but trying to access from `int main()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your return value in the main function.

```
struct Activity {
string ID;
string Name;
string quantitiy;
};

Activity* fillStructure(ifstream &fileActivity) {

int i = 0;
int numberOfElements = numberOfLines(fileActivity);
Activity* myActivity = new Activity[numberOfElements];

while (i < numberOfElements)
{
    getline(fileActivity, myActivity[i].ID, ',');
    getline(fileActivity, myActivity[i].Name, ',');
    getline(fileActivity, myActivity[i].quantitiy, '\n');
    i++;
}

fileActivity.close();

return myActivity;
}


int main(){

ifstream fileActivity ("test.txt", ifstream::in);
Activity* retFile;

retFile = fillStructure(fileActivity);

cout << retFile[1].ID << endl;

return 0;
}
```

---

Declare the return Type of the *fillStructure* function in the *main* function like this:

```
Activity* retFile;
```

This codesnippet works for me